# Why do the vectors perpendicular to [1, 1, 1] and [1, 2, 3] fall on a line, as opposed to a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

And what's the intuition here? This is question 6(c) in pset 1.2, Strang's Linear Algebgra, 4th Ed.

Comment: What shape do the vectors perpendicular to only one of those vectors form? What does the intersection of two of those shapes look like?

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply! The vectors perpendicular to any three-dimensional vector lie on a plane. Because these two vectors are linearly independent, the two planes created here intersect on a line.